# Upgrade script - Create new select attribute with options

Tags: product, attributes, magento-1

I would like to create a new product attribute with some predefined options using an upgrade script.

I have an upgrade script working, so the only thing i dont know how to do is to add the drop down options along with the attribute.

I am adding my attribute inside my modules upgrade script using the following:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', "shirt_size", array(
    'type'       => 'int',
    'input'      => 'select',
    'label'      => 'Shirt Size',
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'required'   => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```

How can I add 3 options along with it: small, medium and large?

I do not want to use a custom source model.  I want normal options

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a classic case where code-generation is your friend.  Stop creating these by hand, and try using [the following free and open source script](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoAttributeMigrationGenerate), (which has also been incorporated into the [`n98-magerun`](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) tool)

For example, the following will duplicate the sample data's color attribute

```
$ magento-create-setup.php color
//WARNING, non false value detected in is_used_for_price_rules.  The setup resource migration scripts may not support this (per 1.7.0.1)
<?php
if(! ($this instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup) )
{
    throw new Exception("Resource Class needs to inherit from " .
    "Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup for this to work");
}

$attr = array (
  'attribute_model' => NULL,
  'backend' => '',
  'type' => 'int',
  'table' => '',
  'frontend' => '',
  'input' => 'select',
  'label' => 'Color',
  'frontend_class' => '',
  'source' => '',
  'required' => '0',
  'user_defined' => '1',
  'default' => '',
  'unique' => '0',
  'note' => '',
  'input_renderer' => NULL,
  'global' => '1',
  'visible' => '1',
  'searchable' => '1',
  'filterable' => '1',
  'comparable' => '1',
  'visible_on_front' => '0',
  'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '0',
  'is_used_for_price_rules' => '1',
  'filterable_in_search' => '1',
  'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
  'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
  'is_configurable' => '1',
  'apply_to' => 'simple',
  'visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
  'position' => '1',
  'wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
  'used_for_promo_rules' => '1',
  'option' => 
  array (
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Green',
      1 => 'Silver',
      2 => 'Black',
      3 => 'Blue',
      4 => 'Red',
      5 => 'Pink',
      6 => 'Magenta',
      7 => 'Brown',
      8 => 'White',
      9 => 'Gray',
    ),
  ),
);
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color', $attr);
```

If you're using the `n98-magerun` version, that'd be

```
$ n98-magerun dev:setup:script:attribute catalog_product color
```

Using code generation will let you get your job done quicker, and as time goes on you'll start to learn the format.

Comment: can we add js event observer like `onClick` and `onChange` in options for attribute?

Answer (score 18):

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'shirt_size', [
    'type'       => 'int',
    'input'      => 'select',
    'label'      => 'Shirt Size',
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'required'   => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'option'     => [
        'values' => [
            0 => 'Small',
            1 => 'Medium',
            2 => 'Large',
        ]
    ],

]);
```

Each element in the `value` array represents an option. You can add the labels for each store view if you have more like this:

```
[
    0=>'Small',
    1=>'Small',
    2=>'Petit'
]
```

Basically it's `store_id=>'Label for store'`

Comment: are the array keys for 'value' significant?  i.e. the '0', '1' and '2' ?

Comment: Marius, do you work for a living? :-)

Comment: @Marty: I don't think they are important.

Comment: @benmarks. I do work for a living and I really enjoy the work I'm doing. I just like from time to time to take 2 minute breaks to answer a question. Do you want me to stop answering? :)

Comment: @benmarks Marius subscribes to the 4-hour work week philosophy.

Comment: @philwinkle. Yeah...4 hour week, but not every week. I don't want to get tired.:)

Comment: @Marius  Can I have the attribute in other group instead of "General" tab? I want to create a new group/tab which I am able to do using **"attribute sets"** in admin panel but I want to do this programmatically. So, what I am trying is creating an attribute and adding to a programmatically generated tab.

Comment: @Mr_Green. Sure you can. You just add this `'group'=> 'Group name here'` in the configuration array when creating the attribute. If the attribute group with that name exists it will be added there. If not, it will be created.

Comment: @Marius I am going through this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module) which I think is different and older than yours (*and also not working*). do you have any link which explains step by step to create an attribute progammatically? (*searching online is giving me all excerpt code answers*)

Comment: This technique failed for me on Magento 1.5, I upgraded to to 1.7 and it worked. Older Magento versions don't look for the array key 'values' in the Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttributeOption function.

Comment: @Marius I am getting an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttribute() on a non-object` I have added `<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>` in config.xml resource script too

Comment: @Dexter add `$installer = $this;` as the first line in the installer script.

Comment: $Marius What is 'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',.can you please explain.

Comment: @mujas. `backend` is the equivalent of `backend_model` column in the `eav_attribute table`. An attribute can support frontend models (that are actually blocks used for rendering the attribute field in the backend), source models (for dropdown and multiselect attributes. this is the source of the options) and backend model. You can use the class you set a backend model to perform actions before the attribute value is saved or after it's loaded. You can use this to perform additional validations or to to alter the value. In this specific case, the array you send from the form is serialized.

Comment: I don't know if this used to work, but it certainly doesn't seem to be a proper solution anymore.

"Call to undefined method Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Array::getAllOptions() in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php on line 201" is the error I get on product edit page and on PLP when enabled for layered navigation

Comment: Your solution works perfectly without the specified backend - I would recommend editing it out

Comment: Are you sure you added the source model to the backend and not the `source` field? `getAllOptions` sounds like a source model method.

Comment: @Marius Can you please add code how we can update the default value as well for dropdown and for Multiselect particularly in mind.

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad you cannot do that from the declaration array only. You need extra code. I had the same question a while back. See this http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/29724/146

Comment: @Marius I had seen this as well but I did not see any code how we can update after add attribute, can you please update code there? for multiselect and select ?

Comment: I can't seam to find the exact code in my project, but I used an adaptation of what Ben posted in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add source model whenever you create attribute type dropdown.

```
'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$valStringArray = array("Nike","Addidas");
createAttribute("Brand","manufacturer",-1,-1,-1,$valStringArray);

//
// Create an attribute.
//
// For reference, see Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction().
//
// @return int|false
//  

function createAttribute($labelText, $attributeCode, $values = -1, $productTypes = -1, $setInfo = -1, $options = -1)
{

    $labelText = trim($labelText);
    $attributeCode = trim($attributeCode);

    if($labelText == '' || $attributeCode == '')
    {
        echo "Can't import the attribute with an empty label or code.  LABEL= [$labelText]  CODE= [$attributeCode]"."<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    if($values === -1)
        $values = array();

    if($productTypes === -1)
        $productTypes = array();

    if($setInfo !== -1 && (isset($setInfo['SetID']) == false || isset($setInfo['GroupID']) == false))
    {
        echo "Please provide both the set-ID and the group-ID of the attribute-set if you'd like to subscribe to one."."<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    echo "Creating attribute [$labelText] with code [$attributeCode]."."<br/>";

    //>>>> Build the data structure that will define the attribute. See
    //     Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction().

    $data = array(
                    'is_global'                     => '1',
                    'frontend_input'                => 'select',
                    'default_value_text'            => '',
                    'default_value_yesno'           => '0',
                    'default_value_date'            => '',
                    'default_value_textarea'        => '',
                    'is_unique'                     => '0',
                    'is_required'                   => '0',
                    'frontend_class'                => '',
                    'is_searchable'                 => '1',
                    'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
                    'is_comparable'                 => '1',
                    'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => '0',
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => '1',
                    'is_visible_on_front'           => '0',
                    'used_in_product_listing'       => '0',
                    'used_for_sort_by'              => '0',
                    'is_configurable'               => '0',
                    'is_filterable'                 => '1',
                    'is_filterable_in_search'       => '1',
                    'backend_type'                  => 'varchar',
                    'default_value'                 => '',
                    'is_user_defined'               => '0',
                    'is_visible'                    => '1',
                    'is_used_for_price_rules'       => '0',
                    'position'                      => '0',
                    'is_wysiwyg_enabled'            => '0',
                    'backend_model'                 => '',
                    'attribute_model'               => '',
                    'backend_table'                 => '',
                    'frontend_model'                => '',
                    'source_model'                  => '',
                    'note'                          => '',
                    'frontend_input_renderer'       => '',                      
                );

    // Now, overlay the incoming values on to the defaults.
    foreach($values as $key => $newValue)
        if(isset($data[$key]) == false)
        {
            echo "Attribute feature [$key] is not valid."."<br/>";
            return false;
        }

        else
            $data[$key] = $newValue;

    // Valid product types: simple, grouped, configurable, virtual, bundle, downloadable, giftcard
    $data['apply_to']       = $productTypes;
    $data['attribute_code'] = $attributeCode;
    $data['frontend_label'] = array(
                                        0 => $labelText,
                                        1 => '',
                                        3 => '',
                                        2 => '',
                                        4 => '',
                                    );

    //<<<<

    //>>>> Build the model.

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

    $model->addData($data);

    if($setInfo !== -1)
    {
        $model->setAttributeSetId($setInfo['SetID']);
        $model->setAttributeGroupId($setInfo['GroupID']);
    }

    $entityTypeID = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
    $model->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeID);

    $model->setIsUserDefined(1);

    //<<<<

    // Save.

    try
    {
        $model->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo "Attribute [$labelText] could not be saved: " . $ex->getMessage()."<br/>";
        if($ex->getMessage() == "Attribute with the same code already exists."){
            if(is_array($options)){
                foreach($options as $_opt){
                    addAttributeValue($attributeCode, $_opt);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    if(is_array($options)){
        foreach($options as $_opt){
            addAttributeValue($attributeCode, $_opt);
        }
    }

    $id = $model->getId();

    echo "Attribute [$labelText] has been saved as ID ($id).<br/>";

    // Asssign to attribute set.
    $model1 = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup');
    $model1->addAttributeToSet(
        'catalog_product', 'Default', 'General', $attributeCode
    ); //Default = attribute set, General = attribute group

    // return $id;
}

function addAttributeValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value)
{
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    if(!attributeValueExists($arg_attribute, $arg_value))
    {
        $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value);
        $result = array('value' => $value);
        $attribute->setData('option',$result);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;
    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value)
        {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
   return false;
}
function attributeValueExists($arg_attribute, $arg_value)
{
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value)
        {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

try this. I have added so many attributes and attribute values through this code and you can assign the attribute to attribute set through this code.