# Magento 2 - front-end selection from database

Tags: magento2, database, frontend, magento-community, drop-downs

**I want to add drop-down(selection) to front-end checkout page. The options must come from database because the data is from third-party and might change.**

What i have so far: 
From magento [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html) i have understand i need to use "Dynamically defined forms" and knockoutJs 'options' => [..] for that. *Is it correct*?

I thought that maybe it is possible to run php script that gets the array like in backend selection [can be done](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/add-custom-drop-down-in-shipping-method). But i do not know how can i get php methods value(returned array) in js page what is using magento devdocs example. Or can i use phtml or php in frontend instead to create drop-down?

Comment: in which section you want to add dropdown ?, shipping address or shipping method.

Comment: In shipping method section. Thanks to  #Jignesh Khunt i found another user who had same problem but the question has not been answered [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108144/add-a-dropdown-field-with-options-to-shippingmethod-on-frontend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Create Following file in your module

file path : `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Shipping" name="checkout.dropdown" after="checkout.root" cacheable="true" template="Vendor_Module::shipping.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body>
</page>
```

Create file for your Block: `Vendor\Module\Block\Shipping.php`

Template file: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/shipping.phtml`

```
<div id="store-container-main" style="display: none">
    //Write your code here.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery'], function ($) {

        var initMyLib = function () {
            if (jQuery('#checkout-shipping-method-load').length) {

                jQuery('.table-checkout-shipping-method').after("<tr class='row'><td colspan='4'>" + jQuery("#store-container-main").html() + "</td></tr>");
                jQuery("#store-container-main").html("");
            } else {
                setTimeout(initMyLib, 2000);
            }
        }
        initMyLib(); //-> initMyLib is undefined
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jignesh Khunt. Could you please explain why the jquery code is necessary in the shipping.phtml file.

Comment: To add your html in shipping method section.