# Adding a product attribute with values and mark one value as default

Tags: product, attributes

I know how I can add a product attribute from an installer script, but how do I tell Magento to use one of the values as default value? (or more values in case it's a multiselect attribute).
I use this code in an installer script to add an attribute with options:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', "some_code_here", array(
    'type'       => 'int', //or varchar if it's multiselect
    'input'      => 'select', //or multiselect
    'label'      => 'Attribute label here',
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'required'   => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'option'     => array (
        'values' => array(
            0 => 'Value 1',
            1 => 'Value 2',
            2 => 'Value 3',
        )
    ),

));
```

So I need to make the `Value 2` be the default value.  Or `Value 2` and `Value 3` in case I create a multiselect attribute

Comment: The only way I know is to get the values after creating the attribute, get the id and update the attribute. I think you tried `default => 'value 2’`?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Thanks. I know this approach, but this is what I'm trying to avoid. I want, if possible, to do it from the install script, without any additional selects and updates. I feel dirty doing it otherwise. But if it's not possible I guess I'll have to tackle it like that.

Comment: @Marius maybe I am still confused. Is your problem that you have an attribute you add in a set-up script but options are added later via the admin? Or another set-up script? Or something completely different ;)

Comment: @DavidManners. I'm adding an attribute via a setup script and along with the attribute I add some options. And through the same setup script I want to set one of the options as default. This has nothing to do with the admin. Let's say I create the attribute `color` with options `Red, Green, Blue` and I want (without admin interaction) the `Green` option to be the default one. I hope this was a bit clearer.

Comment: @Marius but if it is all the same set-up script then isn't setting the default as Fabian said the best option?

Comment: @DavidManners. So you will get the big picture. I'm trying to do this for one custom EAV entity, but it works the same as the for products. I guess I will take that approach if I don't have an alternative. I was just hoping for a more elegant solution. If I don't get an other answer I will "force" Fabian to write that as an answer.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Might as well write your comment as an answer. I guess there is no way of doing this from the install script elegantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***tl;dr:*** For **select** attributes this cannot be declared directly in the initial `addAttribute()` call; two calls are required.

In order to set the default value, `eav_attribute.default`must be set with the primary key value from the `eav_attribute_option` table At a high level the need for two calls is apparent by looking at the flow and function of the `addAttribute()` and `addAttributeOption()` methods:

1. Prepare values
2. Insert/update into the `eav_attribute` table
3. Insert/update set/group
4. **Call `addAttributeOption()` to insert/update option values**

The only hope then would be that `addAttributeOption()` will be able to update the `eav_attribute` record. However, there is no code which does this. The only tables accessed by this method are `eav_attribute_option` and `eav_attribute_option_value`.

It is therefore necessary to call `getAttribute()` after the initial `addAttribute()` call, grab the attribute option ID and then call `updateAttribute()`.

**Edit:**

After the earlier answer I couldn't help but verify my answer against the existing code; after all, for `catalog_product` entities we have a nice MVC flow to follow thanks to the attribute CRUD GUI. And there it was, in `\Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction()`, that I saw the attribute model being set with the following data just before being saved:

[image: Option and option configuration data visualized with PhpStorm & Xdebug]

Note that the attribute's `default` value has references to the `value` keys. Do a little digging and you end up at `\Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption()`, which is called from this resource's `_afterSave()` method - just as you'd expect given that we need to have an `eav_attribute` record to update. You can even see how multiselect and select defaults are handled in the same place, just before the final update:

```
$bind  = array('default_value' => implode(',', $attributeDefaultValue));
$where = array('attribute_id =?' => $object->getId());
$adapter->update($this->getMainTable(), $bind, $where);
```

So, another alternative is to work directly with the resource model.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very disappointed in this. I took the `updateAttribute` approach, but there should be a way to do this elegantly. Maybe in Magento 2. oh...and nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but... too bad I'm wrong! Trying to figure out why though.

Comment: What do you mean you are wrong. To bad you are right :)

Comment: Updated - thought I was wrong, but I wasn't. It's possible to work directly with the resource model, and there is a precedent for this in how attributes are saved via the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Great minds thing alike. I ended up in the same place for inspiration. This is exactly how I handled this in the mean time :)

Comment: TBH it's kind of insane. You'd think that `eav/setup` would work with the attribute model, but instead it writes to the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

In installer These are the two line after addAttribute which ben explain to add default:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
. . . . 
. . . . 
. . . .     
$attr = $setup->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code');
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product',$attr['attribute_id'],'default_value', 'default_value1,default_value2,default_value3,default_value4');
```

attribute_code: will be your attribute code
default_value1: will be your corresponding value separate by ,