# How to set the default option in existing dropdown attribute

Tags: attributes, magento-1, dropdown-attribute

How do I set an option in a dropdown attribute as the default? I am adding the options to an existing attribute with this code where $aName is an array of names.

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$aName = array("Name1", "Name2");

$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $attr_id; 

for($iCount=1;$iCount<sizeof($aName);$iCount++){
        $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $aName[$iCount];   
        $aOption['order']['option'.$iCount] = $iCount   ;  
}

$installer->addAttributeOption($aOption);
$installer->endSetup();
```

I think the answer is in Stackoverflow [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29724/adding-a-product-attribute-with-values-and-mark-one-value-as-default) but I don't know how to apply it. In my case the Attribute exists, I'm just updating the option list and setting the default.

Comment: I found the answer for setting the  position and included it in my sample code, but I still need to understand how to set an option as the default.

Answer (score 0):

You are using method **addAttributeOption($option)**

Such method consist following row:

```
            if (!isset($values[0])) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('eav')->__('Default option value is not defined'));
            }
```

All appearances the default value will be in $values[0]. Try to look through this method. Most probably you will find more interesting things

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @zhartaunik, you can designate the first option as the default. Another way is to set the *default_value* in the table *eav_attribute*:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/attribute')->load($attr_id);
$attribute->setDefaultValue($default);
$attribute->save();
```