# Magento : Custom extension overwrites gender values. How to Fix?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer, dropdown-attribute

Shop owner called telling me the gender select in the store contains `Apple` and `Banana`  instead of `male` and `female`. Turns our this was the case in all form frondend/backend.

After some digging I found an extension with an mysql4-upgrade file. The only place I got any Apples, so this must be causing this problem:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'p_layout', array(
             'label'             => 'Motiv',
             'type'              => 'varchar',
             'input'             => 'select',
             'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
             'frontend'          => '',
             'source'            => '',
             'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
             'visible'           => true,
             'required'          => true,
             'user_defined'      => true,
             'searchable'        => false,
             'filterable'        => false,
             'comparable'        => false,
             'option'            => array (
                                            'value' => array(
                                                '1' => array('Apple'),
                                                '2' => array('Banana'),
                                            )
                                        ),
             'visible_on_front'  => false,
             'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
             'unique'            => false
));

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'p_layout');


if ($attributeId) {
    $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeId; //p_layout
    $option['value']['optionone'][0] = 'Apple';
    $option['value']['optionone'][1] = 'Apple';
    $option['value']['optionone'][2] = 'Apple';
    $option['value']['optionone'][3] = 'Apple';
    $option['value']['optiontwo'][0] = 'Banana';
    $option['value']['optiontwo'][1] = 'Banana';
    $option['value']['optiontwo'][2] = 'Banana';
    $option['value']['optiontwo'][3] = 'Banana';

    $installer->addAttributeOption($option);
    $installer->addAttributeSet('catalog_product', 'Stuff');
```

In `eav_attribute_option_value` I found `option_id` 1 and 2 being `Apple` and `Banana`. I guess during an update or the recent page move to another server this was overwritten.

Any idea how to fix this? I would like to avoid having this mess again...

Looks to pretty much like this: [Upgrade script - Create new select attribute with options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/upgrade-script-create-new-select-attribute-with-options)

Could the missing `'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table'` causing this problem?

Or is `'1' => array('Apple')` the problem? I noticed in other places they set the value like this: `array('Apple', 'Banana')`

Comment: which magento version? Usually in System->Configuration->Customer Configuration you can define the prefixes by semicolon seperated values for "Prefix"

Comment: It is ce-1.7.0.2 and yes you can set `Prefix Dropdown Options` but not gender. There is only an option to `Show Gender`. I got that on `optional` but the values seem to be predefined in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Setup.php`