# How to create Custom Attribute in magento by script which should have following property

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.0.1, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

hi I want to create extesnion...and for that I need to create attribute which should have following front end properties....

```
Use in Quick Search ----> true
Use in Advanced Search ---> true
Comparable on Front-end ---> true
Used in Product Listing --- >true 
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end --- > true
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend --->true
Use for Promo Rule Conditions --->true
Use In Search Results Layered Navigation-->true
Use In Layered Navigation --> true
```

this is following properties of my attributes which is  needed for me but its not working with this code...

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();   

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'test_attribute1', array(
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'test',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_layout',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => true,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => true,
    'filterable'        => true,
    'comparable'        => true,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'unique'            => false,
    'group'             => 'General'

));
$installer->endSetup();
```

How this will be possible by custom script........

Comment: Can you include what errors are you facing when you used the above code ?

Comment: @Prateek attribute is created but all front end property is no.....

Comment: For that, you are missing some properties in your addAttribute call. Take a look at _prepareValues() method in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup class. It lists all the allowed properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue several times. Seems like missing one of the attribute creates the attribute but left it in an unstable state.

I suggest you modify the following script from this post to fit your needs: [Upgrade script - Create new select attribute with options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/upgrade-script-create-new-select-attribute-with-options)

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();   

$attr1 = array (
  'attribute_model' => NULL,
  'backend' => '',
  'type' => 'int',
  'table' => '',
  'frontend' => '',
  'input' => 'select',
  'label' => 'Brands',
  'frontend_class' => '',
  'source'=> 'brands/attribute_source_brands',
  'required' => '1',
  'user_defined' => '1',
  'default' => '',
  'unique' => '0',
  'note' => '',
  'input_renderer' => NULL,
  'global' => '1',
  'visible' => '1',
  'searchable' => '1',
  'filterable' => '1',
  'comparable' => '1',
  'visible_on_front' => '1',
  'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
  'is_used_for_price_rules' => '1',
  'filterable_in_search' => '1',
  'used_in_product_listing' => '1',
  'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
  'is_configurable' => '0',
  'visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
  'position' => '1',
  'wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
  'used_for_promo_rules' => '1');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product','brands',$attr1);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: very helpful....................

Comment: Didn't it help ?

Comment: very good....helpful without any question.........

Comment: Ok, feel free to mark your question as answered if it helped. Good day