# Custom source model or attribute options

Tags: magento2, attributes, dropdown-attribute, source-model

I have a few attributes that come with input select or multiselect. I have created source models to provide options for inputs. Everything seems to work (values are saved). But today I realized that also attribute options can be added.

Can anyone tell me what is the difference? Should I use source model or options? I have noticed thanks to this tutorial:
[Upgrade script - Create new select attribute with options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/upgrade-script-create-new-select-attribute-with-options/15251#15251)
that labels for options ar bind with store ids - how it should look like if I want to add the same options for every store (I have one website and one store). How to add more options for one attribute in sql script?

Comment: Options are admin-editable, a source is not. Furthermore, you'd use a source when you want it re-usable for other attributes/configs. Also, check `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttributeOption()`. I should expand this into an answer, but haven't got the time right now.

Comment: I think I get a clue - source model is more general thing and that's the difference I have noticed - it can't be editable... So if you have some time later - feel free to write some more thoughts. Thanks!